# i want custom json format using django

Tags: json, django, format, retrofit

Django is new for me, i want custom json response.
i try to get response from server using android app retrofit.
response by server accurate. 
i need to match json format please help me, thanks

i got json format like

```
  {
    "username": "admin",
    "token": "xxx"
}
```

but i want

```
responseCode{
   responseCode:xxx,
   ResponseData:
         {token:xxx,username:xxx}
    }
```

code that return json format data

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
token = serializers.CharField(allow_blank = True , read_only = True)
username = serializers.CharField(required = False , allow_blank=True)
#email = serializers.EmailField(label="Email Adress",required = False, allow_blank=True)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        #'email',
        'password',
        'token',



    ]
    extra_kwargs ={"password":
                    {"write_only":True  
                    }
    }
def validate(self, data):
    user_obj = None
    #email = data.get('email', None)
    username = data.get("username", None)
    password = data["password"]
    if not username:
            raise ValidationError("A username or email is required to login")

    user=User.objects.filter(
            #Q(email=email)|
            Q(username=username)

        ).distinct()
    #user = user.exclude(email=None)
    if user.exists() and user.count() == 1 :
        user_obj = user.first()
    else:
        raise ValidationError("username not valid.")

    if user_obj:
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise ValidationError("Incorrect credentials please try again")


    #token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user_obj)
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user_obj)

    data["token"] = token.key
    data["username"] = user_obj


    return data
```

i tried something like this

```
# responseCode = {}
# responseData = {}

# responseData['token'] = token.key
# responseData['username'] = user_obj
# responseCode['responseData'] = responseData
# data["responseCode"] = responseCode
```

but not work, please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
responseCode{
   responseCode:xxx,
   ResponseData:
         {token:xxx,username:xxx}
    }
```

is not a valid json file.

you should get it like that :

```
data["responseCode"]={
   "responseCode":"xxx",
   "ResponseData":
         {
             token:token.key,
             username:user_obj
          }
    }
```

and then, when you call data it will return

```
responseCode:{
   responseCode:xxx,
   ResponseData:
         {token:xxx,username:xxx}
    }
```

Comment: what did you get?

Answer (score -1):

A valid JSON format is like:

```
{
    key1 : value1,
    key2 : value2,
}
```

where we can have nested values also. so, a nested value looks like

```
{
    key1 : {
              key_nested1 : value,
              key_nested2 : value
            },
    key2 : value
 }
```

Now, once you understand this, we can easily translate our required values in the JSON format. So, In Python , we use dictionary to create this structure as you have already tried in your code.

```
JSONFormat = {}  #corresponds to empty json file

#now we need to insert key value pairs
JSONFormat["ResponseCode"]= "Fill your response code here"

#this is how our json will look now
#{
#     ResponseCode : "Fill your reponse code here"
#}
```

Now, ResponseData has a nested dictionary as its value
so we need to do these two things

1. create a dictionary
2. take that dictionary as a value for key "ResponseData" as shown below

   ```
       ResponseDataValue = { }        #create the dictionary
       ResponseDataValue["Token"] = "Your Token Here"
       ResponseDataValue["Username"] = "Your User Name"

       #now we take this value and place it against out json_format dict

       JSONFormat["ResponseData"] = ResponseDataValue
   ```

so in the end you can have your required format

```
{
     ResponseCode :"Your Code",
     ResponseData : {
                        Token : "Your Token",
                        Username : "the username"
                    }
}
```